# How to Find My Proper Ip Address to Connect to Another Computer Remotely

Tags: networking, ip, port, ip-address, forwarding

My friend wanted to connect to my computer using Remote Desktop Connection. But the problem is I am confused what my Ip address is.

My computer is connected to the internet via router via broadband internet network. My ip address is dynamic.

Here, my main purpose is not only the remote connection but also learning how dynamic ip connect to another pc.

I searched for ip address on Google. They show me an ip address. But I think it is not mine, it's related with the router or broadband network. I also find a WAN ip (it is different from that i found on google) on router settings. It did't work.

I used Team Viewer. It worked perfectly. But I want to do that manually because I am going to make a multiplayer game on GM8.

It will helpful if someone explain about ip and port forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

Teamviewer is a great tool, but uses different techniques than what you plan to do. Teamviewer always uses an outgoing connection and use a mediator on the Internet to connect you and the other PC.

You should ask your Internet provider if he technically enables you to be reachable from the outside Internet. Often this is not possible at all, even if you configure your router the correct way.
When you ask this you can ask him if you have a static IP.

Comment: I just wanted to make a multiplayer game. So I need to learn about IP passing and port forwarding. Connecting two PC may be a great practice before make a multiplayer game.
I think I can also connect with another PC with my dynamic WAN ip. I'm confused what is my WAN ip.

Comment: @RafsunMasudPrince you should really learn about the basics gabhijit expained to you. Because otherwise you will expose yourself to security risks. Playing with router configuration and messing it up unknowingly is like leaving open the front door to your appartment .

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not aware of basics of IP networking, so I'd strongly advise against trying this on your router as wrong settings would render it useless. But here's for your information how port forwarding and IP Address and dynamic DNS can be used to solve your problem.

Basically your ISP is likely to give you a router having an IP address. If this IP address is a global IP address, it is possible to connect to this IP from outside. How do you find out whether your IP address is global? Look for your WAN IP address setting. If it is in `10.x.x.x` or `192.168.x.x` range, it's unlikely to be global and in that case it might not be possible to connect to your computer from outside - without help of a third server (some kind of a registration server, where you connect and register your application). The Registration server would determine your globally visible IP address and then convey it to another Application who is interested in connecting to it. This is somewhat complicated to make it work (but if you intend to make a game - this is something you'd have to do regardless). This is mostly how software like TeamViewer would work.

If you have a global IP address - it means it can technically be reached from anywhere in the world. In that case you could use port forwarding to make things work for you. Port forwarding works basically as follows - You expose a certain port (on TCP) to external world - say 8000 and then you make a setting like following on your router.

```
<TCP>-<RouterIP>-8000 --> <TCP>-<Your LAN IP><Your application Port>
```

(You can find you lan ip using `ipconfig` on windows or `ifconfig` on Linux).

Now all connections coming to port 8000 would be directed to your application. You might want to do it on UDP as well and the protocol above would change. That is how you 'open' a few ports to be accessible from outside, configure them on your router and then run corresponding applications on your network.

There's another thing called dynamic DNS, where the IP address you use if it is dynamic (and global) can be registered with a Dynamic DNS server so that you don't have to know and remember the current WAN IP Address. But that can be for later.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the information.
My WAN ip is like 10.0.x.xx. Can I connect with other computer using this ip? If not then how Team Viewer and other services connect?
And I learnt more about port forwarding from you. Thanks.

Comment: As I explained - the WAN IP is just an IP on your router. This gets converted @ a globally visible IP Address @ your ISPs end through something called NAT. What you see on 'what is my IP on google' is indeed this IP. Now what things like this do is - they register this IP and a port (that made a request to teamviewer server) and when another Teamviewer client asks it gives that port and IP and now both port and IP address is known so they can connect.

Comment: Oh, Okay. Do you know which address should I use to connect through Remote Desktop Connection?

Comment: No I am not really aware of remote desktop protocol. So can't tell - but even that'd need some registration  as described above if you are behind NAT which you cannot control.

Comment: @gabhijit it is not worth the effort, he only wants a fast solution and is reluctant to learn